# Mocking Rest Get Method

Tags: rest, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

I would like an explanation about Mock and Rest. I'm a little bit confused on how should I simulate this scenario:

- Aplication A (GET method by mock)
- Aplication B (GET method by mock)
- Aplication C (POST method by SpringBoot)

At aplication C I should consume data from aplication A and aplication B and calculate a return from a method.

I would like to know what tools should I use to simulate those mocks. I will only have one instance of Eclipse to make it all (app A, B and C)?

Comment: Mock-Objects are objects without logic. So you need to pre-define what they are doning, when they get called or just write empty services which are returning pre-defined data all the time. 
Are you working with real Mocks or just normal Objects which are simulating a service?

Comment: search for `@RestClientTest` annotation

Comment: I would like to work with real Mocks. Ok, I gonna look for @RestClientTest. So on the same Project structure I must define my mock test?